# Duplicate events Facebook Analytics iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

We want to stop Facebook Auto Events logging that includes AddToCart, Purchase, InitiateCheckout. We have toggled off Event Suggestions in Events manager and we have also forced through code to not log auto events. However, we are still getting auto events which are conflicting with standard events that we are manually logging via code and hence creating problem for us while using them in Facebook AdSets.

PS:- We are testing events in Event Manager's Test Events.